# Jquery print area print css colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I'm using printarea jquery: https://github.com/RitsC/PrintArea

But I'm having a little trouble to print colors when I printing

I want to print like this when I print
   https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/815x185q90/673/ImZBHd.jpg

That's what I have:
   https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/437x549q90/674/dDkSRU.jpg

this is my JS:

```
$('#imprimir').on('click', function(){// busca os dados ao clicar no botão
    $(".area_impressao").printArea({
        mode       : "iframe",
        standard   : "html5",
        popTitle   : 'relatorio',
        popClose   : false,
        extraCss   : '../css/impressao_retrato.css', 
        extraHead  : '',
        retainAttr : ["id","class","style"],
        printDelay : 500, // tempo de atraso na impressao
        printAlert : true,
        printMsg   : 'Aguarde a impressão'
    });
});
```

I Also tried to change this line but didnt work:

```
extraCss   : '../css/impressao_retrato.css, ../css/style.css, ../css/main.css',
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm facing it too

Comment: yeah I had to remove bootstrap and chosen css from the page and just use the style that i need for this page

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve your problem:

Create an CSS file, put all your printable elements in it (those visible when you print). Please, do the World a favor and don't print your attempts, use a pdf generator as the printer.

```
@media print {
.myCustom{color:#88000;background-color:#FF0000}
/*Set here your custom stiles as you want, each element*/
}
```